# Firebase push notifications iOS: getting NotRegistered. Why?

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented firebase push notifications in React native on Android side: all things are working fine.

In the iOS side I'm getting `NotRegistered`, why?

That's the response:

```
data:NOTIFCATION {
  deviceToken: 'diTk7DNPS9KsRTPSFlpSoU:APA91bEaNxB9W0g6m8487W37qTgUYmqGA2GfN1tPbwI1q60WAsHFrCdhbYzEZO-q5lfY1s3epNsSKhHpxO-OLYMGED3ZeYi_f7DHUrOpxMgC0QE7KJFslZwk3-CKnqbfkClu3tzUL6_X',
  title: 'Extended Session',
  message: 'Please extend Your parking Session expire soon'
}
{"multicast_id":8523782171183643556,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]} Something has gone wrong!
```

Answer (score 1):

*(the answer is in bold)*

I encountered this error and searched for answers from various sources. I spent two days finding the issue and testing all possible solutions. Eventually, I discovered this problem is more likely to occur when running the app in a simulator. However, everything worked fine when I ran the app on my physical device.

**Try to run it on your device!**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) if you correctly registered the iOS token, there are some possible causes:

An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:

- If the client app unregisters with FCM.
- If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if
  the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNs
  Feedback Service reported the APNs token as invalid.
- If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide
  to refresh registration tokens, or the APNs token has expired for iOS
  devices).
- If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to
  receive messages.

For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.